# Calculate median/mode but ignore black colour

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

In OpenCV Python, I have masked out parts of the image, thus they are black. I need to calculate the median (or mode) colour that occurs in the image but ignore the masked/black pixels.

How can I do this because the functions I use still consider black pixels AFAIK:

```
mode = scipy.stats.mode(img) # will consider black pixels wont it?
median = np.median(img, axis=(0,1)) # will consider black pixels wont it?
```

Comment: Just index the image where it's not black. You can use your mask. `np.median(img[mask])` ?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds can you explain more please. Is mask an array the same size as img and all masked out areas are 0 (or 255?),  is mask a 3 channel or 1 channel? etc.

Comment: Will `scipy.stats.mode(img[img != 255])` work?

Comment: What @AlexanderReynolds means is, that if you index the image with the mask, it won't regard the black pixels for the function. You can picture black and white in images as boolean `True` and `False`. So img[mask] indexes the image with a boolean array that is `False` for black pixels no matter what representation (binary, 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit....). The mask-array has the same size as the original.

Comment: Also, you probably need to clarify what means black color. E.g. color (0, 0, 0) is truly black, but (0, 1, 0) is almost black. You probably need to introduce some threshold value to separate almost black colors